# How to add the project license to the build with and Angular CLI project for xRay license scanning

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli, x-ray

Our project has a custom license written into license attribute in package.json.

When we ng build the project we can see a 3rdpartylicenses.txt generated into dist folder with all the dependencies licenses included.

Our custom license is not present.

As far as I know xRay scans package.json into the build archive or check license.txt file against a license database ( https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-xray-detects-package-licenses ).

How can we add our license into the build ?

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**
After some explorations :

One solution would be to use simply npm publish to pack the dist folder into a tar archive and the package.json, license.txt and even README.md would be inside the archive.

Is it a good solution ? ( my problem is the docker deployment that uses actually tha application archive with the generated content at that root of the archive, so we would have to change the deployment scripts )

Answer (score 1):

If you are making an npm package it is simply adding the list of files you want to add during the build phase. Go to the ng-package.json file inside the project and add an "assets" entry and pass it the list of files.

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/ngp-material-rating",
  "lib": {
     "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  },
 "assets": [ "./LICENSE.md", "./README.md" ]
}
```

In this example I have added the files LICENCE.md and Readme.Md